# Read From Microsoft Excel (.xlsx) file and Insert into a DB using Python?

Tags: python, database, excel, postgresql, xlrd

I'm working on an application to read an `.xlsx`, (Excel File) with headers and insert the rows, as-is, into a DB Table in a Postgres DB.

I presume i would be using the XLRD library.

Any ideas on How to do this?

I'm using Python 2.6.6.

Comment: Instead of asking how to do it, you should rather try it and ask for specific help on a topic that doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

By far the easiest way will be to transform it to CSV, then use `psql`'s `\copy`, or [`psycopg2`'s `COPY` support](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#using-copy-to-and-copy-from). Any command-line `.xlsx` to `CSV` converter would then work for you when invoked via the built-in `subprocess` module, or `popen`/`system` on older Pythons. You wouldn't need any special Python libs. This would also let you use a converter, like OpenOffice / LibreOffice's command-line mode, that can handle all sorts of other tabular data too.

If you want to do it all in Python you could use [the `xlrd` lib you mentioned](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd) and feed the tuples one by one into `psycopg2`'s `copy_from`, so you stream the rows to PostgreSQL using only Python code. You should find [existing examples of psycopg2 based programs that use `copy_from`](https://github.com/Kozea/psycopg/blob/master/examples/copy_from.py) easy to adapt to using `xlrd` as a data source instead of Python lists / csv input / whatever.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel, format the XLS file so that there are no headers and no blank columns (basically, just make a table). This can also work with LibreOffice. Then, save the file as a CSV. Then, view your CSV file with a text editor and verify that things are in order.

Once you are happy with the content of the CSV, it's quite simple to write a python code that reads each row and then creates a list of each field. Here is a 30 second version of code:

```
with open('example.csv','r') as csv_file:
    full = csv_file.read().split('\n')
    for line in full:
    values = line.split(',')
        print values
```

In the 'for' loop, you can access each element of the list individually, i.e. 'values[0]'

Comment: Please *never* advise people to manually parse CSV! Python [contains the `csv` module as a built-in module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) for a reason. It's easier *and* safer than hand-hacking CSV-like text. Consider how your 30-second example handles `"24 SomeStreet, Sometown", "Somecountry"`. It doesn't - kaboom. [You can wrangle HTML using regular expressions, but it's a terrible idea](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html). This is the same kind of thing.

Comment: I was referring to the use of the XLRD Python Library to parse XLS/XLSX files directly as a data stream...! - already know about parsing CSV's and thats much simpler too... Thanks anyway, but i got my problem solved by myself...